# Problema al alinear verticalmente una imagen dentro de un figure

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo un problema con este sencillo html:

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
  line-height: 150px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

figure {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/8d4/anemone-1372191.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
  </a>

  <a href="#">Texto del enlace</a>
</div>
```

No entiendo que la imagen (img) no aparezca centrada dentro de su contenedor (el figure con fondo rojo) el cual sí esta correctamente centrado

Si cambiamos el position de la imagen a absolute entonces funciona bien:

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
  line-height: 150px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

figure {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative; /* añadiendo esto */
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute; /* ...y esto */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/8d4/anemone-1372191.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
  </a>

  <a href="#">Texto del enlace</a>
</div>
```

¿Por qué se descentra en la primera versión?

Comment: podrías añadir el código de la parte que no te funciona en vez de poner enlace a la web con el código incluido. Si en un futuro dicha página desapareciese la respuesta a tu pregunta no le valdría a nadie.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. Lo tendré en cuenta para futuras preguntas. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No solo te sirve `display: block` como te dice @MarcosGallardo, si no también:

- `flex`
- `table`
- `table-cell`
- `table-column`
- `table-header-group`
- `table-footer-group`
- `table-row`
- Y muchas más

Aquí lo importante es saber **el por qué** sucede ésto y la respuesta es para nada de otro mundo. El problema aquí es `line-height` ya que **se está heredando** en el elemento `figure`, haciendo que la imagen se salga de cuadro. La razón de por qué cambiando la `img` a `block` elimina éste problema es porque ésta propiedad **afecta sólo a elementos en línea o mixtos** (`inline` y `inline-block`). Es por ésto que si no le cambias el display a `img` tendrá su valor por defecto, que es `inline-block`.

Tu problema lo puedes solucionar tan sólo **sobreescribiendo el valor heredado para `line-height`**:

```
figure {
  line-height: initial;
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
  line-height: 150px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

figure {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  line-height: initial;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/8d4/anemone-1372191.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
  </a>

  <a href="#">Texto del enlace</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes solucionar agregando al `img` la propiedad `display: block;`.

Demo:

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
  line-height: 150px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

figure {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/8d4/anemone-1372191.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
  </a>

  <a href="#">Texto del enlace</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué hace este código? Lee [answer].

Comment: Hola, Julio. Si bien, el código centra la imagen horizontalmente, debes explicarlo, porque para muchas personas puede parecer muy obvio mientras que para otros, no tanto. Siempre se debe explicar el código, por muy pequeño que sea. Al menos, los puntos claves.